# What is the name of this basic machine learning example?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

Some time ago I was reading a book on machine learning in which they had an example that would take some data and try to determine based on weather, temperature, humidity and Wind if a sports team would play or not.

It looked similar to [this example](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/1-use-class-playtennis-training-example-incldes-14-days--15-marks-construct-naive-bayes-cl-q40346741) and I was wondering if anyone could name this famous example so I can find a Python library that does the same thing.

Comment: it is a basic binary classification problem, where the inputs are weather measurements and the output is one of two classes ie: play, no-play

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the dataset has not an official or a common name. In their text book ["Data Mining"](https://www.elsevier.com/books/data-mining-practical-machine-learning-tools-and-techniques/witten/978-0-12-374856-0) Witten et al. refer to it as "The Weather Problem". The example is based in on a dataset described in ["Induction of Decision Trees"](https://svivek.com/teaching/machine-learning/fall2020/readings/quinlan.pdf) by Quinlan in 1986. Accordingly, it has been used in many books as an example to illustrate decision trees.

Using key words such as "weather", "weather problem", "decision tree" or "play tennis" might still lead to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This specific example is trying to predict a variable which can have two values, either yes or no. In data science terms this would be a classification problem. Part a asks to use a naive bayes classifier for this data, which can easily be done using the [scikit-learn library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html).